# Change tab order of some ActiveX and Form Controls

Tags: vba, excel

I have created some `text-boxes` (`ActiveX Controls`), `checkboxes` (`Form Controls`) and one `end-button` (`Form Controls`) in my Worksheet and wanted to `tab` between them.

How can I achieve that?

Maybe it's only possible with VBA.

Thank you very much in advance for your answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this via the properties (that I'm aware of), but you can always just use the `KeyDown` event, trap the tab key, and then use `.Verb` to set focus to where you want.  For example, if you have a CheckBox, a ComboBox, and a TextBox:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 9 Then
        ComboBox1.Verb
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 9 Then
        TextBox1.Verb
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 9 Then
        CheckBox1.Verb
    End If
End Sub
```