# Can we use tab/enter to move on to other TextBox in Excel Worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I wonder if I can move from TextBox to TextBox in a worksheet by using tab or enter just like it can in userform where we can set the TabOrder.
(The reason for not using userform is that my sheet is quite complex, which building it on a worksheet is much easier and more flexible for adjusting the size and position.)

Comment: I recommend to still use a UserForm because: 1) Stay away from ActiveX controls where possible, there is a high probability that they cause any kind of issues. 2) UserForms are made exactly for that task, worksheets are not! 3) You could use the `TextBox1_KeyDown` event to trigger on tab or enter and write some code to focus the next text box but this will bloat up your code and is even more complex than using a UserForm. • Alternative way, let the user input data in cells instead of TextBoxes.

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40766347/change-tab-order-of-some-activex-and-form-controls)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change tab order of some ActiveX and Form Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40766347/change-tab-order-of-some-activex-and-form-controls)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. They really help me get the idea of how it could be done. Anyway, currently in my worksheet there are about 180-200 TextBoxes. If I followed your answer method, I would have to put the codes into every TextBoxes. So, is there any way to make a loop (a single set of code) for this? For example, some thing similar to this
a = a + 1
Me.Controls("TextBox" & a).Active

Comment: This is why I suggested to use a UserForm. Because it is easier. If there are 200 TextBoxes then you should re-think your general approach. You probably chose the wrong control and a ListView would be better. I cannot imagine any reason why not to use a UserForm for that. • If you try to explain (in your question) what you are trying to do in general then we can probably suggest a better way to do that.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. The purpose of this worksheet is to make a filling form to get data from a paper form. So, to make it easier for others to fill the data in, I have to make the worksheet looks like the paper.   In this case, there are many products; 1 product/1 paper form. IMO, working in a worksheet is easier to manipulate the contents because there are some parts of the form that are the same in each product. So, I can just copy/paste those parts for other forms.

Comment: You can easily make the UserForm looking like a paper form by making a JPEG of that paper form and then use the `Picture` property to add it into the background of the UserForm. Then just put your TextBoxes at the right positions of the "paper" form. Working with UserForms is as easy as with worksheets (you can [export/import UserForms to duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16817764/duplicate-user-form-in-excel-vba) them) or you can also copy parts of one form to another. I see only advantages of using UserForms.

Comment: That's really cool. I have tried as you suggested. The problem I find is that the height of the page is to large. So, I have to use ScrollBar and I have tried once with the codes that enable mouse's scroll wheel to work. The codes do not work with MultiPage. Do you have any advice?